# Mathematical induction without simplifying equations or inequalities

Tags: secondary-education, discrete-math

We discuss lot of questions related to mathematical expressions consisting equations or inequalities in mathematical induction. What are the examples where we can apply mathematical induction as the method of proof in proving statements without involving  equation or inequality for advanced level students. I think this kind of problems may be quite interesting to improve creative skills in mathematics.
Here is one example to get the clear picture of the issue 
Finitely many lines divide a plane into regions. Show that these regions can be coloured by two colours in such a way that neighboring regions have different colours.

Comment: Here is another example, prove that for any $n ≥ 1$ a $2ⁿ × 2 ⁿ $ checkerboard with $1 × 1$ corner square removed can be tilted using L tromionoes, because here too we don't need simplifications of equations or inequalities.

Comment: Similar question on  [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294677/looking-for-induction-problems-that-are-not-formula-based)

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few examples (for students at very different levels, since it's rather subjective what constitutes an "advanced level"):

- The task in the [Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) puzzle is solvable. (The Towers of Hanoi are often used as an example for a recursive algorithm - but one can, of course, also frame it as an example for induction.)
- A classic: existence of the prime factorization of integers.
- A compact metric space (or, more generally, a compact topological Hausdorff space) which is countable and infinite contains infinitely many isolated points.
- Identity theorem for polynomials: if a complex polynomial of degree $d \ge 0$ vanishes at $d+1$ distinct points, then it is $0$ (can be shown by induction over $d$, splitting off a linear factor in the inductive step).

  (One might argue that there is certainly a small computational part in the induction step - but I'd argue that the overall argument is theoretical rather than computional in nature, so it's not one of typical "Show the following equality by writing down a chain of identities in the induction step" problems.)
- Every planar polygon with $n$ vertices can be written as the union of $n-2$ triangles.

  (For non-convex polygons this contains a subtlety, though: one first needs to show that every polygon can be split into two polygons by connecting to appropriately chosen vertices.)
- Here's a weird one (I'd only recommend it for students who are up to dealing with technical subtleties):

  For a set $X$ and an associative binary operation $\circ: X \times X \to X$, composing finitely many elements $x_1, \dots, x_n$ (in this order) by any use of parantheses yields the same result.

  Note that, for this exercise to make sense, one a priori needs to define an $n$-ary operation $X^n \to X$ by fixing an order of evaluation, e.g. $x_1 \circ \dots \circ x_n := \Big( \dots (x_1 \circ x_2) \circ \dots x_n \Big)$.

  (The claimed property seems intuitively clear and in each algebra course I have ever participated in, as a student or teacher, we just glossed over this without really doing the induction - and, as I said above, I would only recommend to discuss it in detail if one has very strong students).

Comment: IME teaching discrete mathematics, these examples all seem very advanced -- usually things the instructor would have to guide students through, and each taking several dense pages in the textbook. Which seems at odds with what the OP is requesting.

Comment: The planar polygon example could be taught to anyone (especially with an additional hypothesis of convexity).

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, maybe they're harder than they look, but a few look doable for this level of student: the triangulation and Hanoi sound interesting.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Hmm, not sure I'm convinced - the existence of the prime factorization (which takes two or three lines rather than several pages) and dividing planar polygons into triangles (say, for convex polgyons if one wants to avoid technical difficulties) are not more difficult than the example at the end of the OP's question, are they? (Regarding the other examples, I was thinking of OP's mentioning of "advanced level students". Admittedly, I didn't put clause attention to the question tags, though.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck: I'm assuming we want the uniqueness result? In Rosen's Discrete Mathematics, the uniqueness is about 3 pages (15 paragraphs, a theorem, definition, 3 lemmas; Sec. 4.3), and that uses but skips justifying Bezout's theorem. Then the existence part comes later, and that's another 3 paragraphs (Sec. 5.2).

Comment: @SueVanHattum: In Rosen, triangulation is 3 pages (16 dense paragraphs, Sec. 5.2). Hanoi is 2 pages (9 paragraphs, Sec. 8.1).

Comment: Ahh, interesting. Maybe I'll look at those when I have some time. I  take it you don't feel Rosen is overcomplicating it? (His text seems unnecessarily dry to me, and seems to make some things harder than they need to be. But I didn't look at these two topics in his text.)

Comment: @SueVanHattum: The details all look necessary to my eye.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: It seems that we misunderstood each other: I conciously wrote *existence* only, because uniqueness is more complicated. Existence (without knowing uniqueness) goes like this: $n=2$ is prime, so assume the result is true for some $n\ge 2$. If $n+1$ is prime there is nothing to show. If it's not prime, then $n+1=ab$ for some $a,b\in \{2, \dots n\}$ and we can thus apply the induction hypothesis to $a$ and $b$. $\square$ I'd say this is absolutely doable in secondary education. Don't you think so? (Of course one should mention that uniqueness holds but isn't so easy).

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Unfortunately, none of the logical machinery would have been covered in any secondary education school I've seen (in US). A lot of details of what counts as base, induction, the assumption, conclusion, and why $a, b <= n$ were left out. It's definitely not something I can give as an exercise even in a terminal community college class for math majors.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins what about if you consider only the number of movements required for the smallest disc when there are n number of discs in the case of towers of hanoi . Here you have very little part of mathematics just to multiply by 2 to prove the result for deductive part. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

The textbook I use for Discrete Mathematics has some lovely inductive proof problems. (And it's OER.) [***Discrete Mathematics: An Open Introduction***, by Oscar Levin](https://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3.html).

I especially like the stamps problem he uses to introduce the topic (section 2.5), and the number of squares problem (in the exercises, #29).

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing much important relevant information .